# Can you work without local admin rights on your work machine as a professional programmer?

Tags: admin, local, rights

I work as a Programming tutor and course developer, in Dot Net using VS 2013 /15'

Owing to college policies I have lost local admin rights to my work machine resulting in many calls to help desk to for install simple actions such as updating Visual Studio (even the extensions!) configuring and updating SQL Server Management Studio, new software, etc.

As a professional programmer, does your employer have such draconian regulations? I have seriously thought of walking away from a job I love over it, its too restrictive for no reason.

I need to make a case that this is an unacceptable working condition.

Comment: @cdonts no, it does not. It is both off-topic and primarily opinion-based (at both SO and Programmers). Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: Your employer will get what they pay for.. if they want to reduce your productivity that's their loss . Play candy crush or something while waiting for helpdesk to get back to you

Comment: *lots* of places are like this, if you ditch this job due to no-admin-rights you may well end up in a similar situation somewhere else. keep notes and track how much time this costs you.but be aware these policies are set from high up and your mgmt may not have any wiggle room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, if your employer is providing the hardware, it's theirs not yours and they have the ultimate say on what's on it and what's not.  Anyone working for a company using their hardware or their network will always be doing so under an acceptable use policy.  Even if the company supports a Bring-Your-Own-Device policy, there will be some form of stipulation that you have certain levels of security on the device.

I think what your argument, though, is about the impact to your productivity.  It's less around the unacceptability of the working condition, and more about the waste that comes into play for you to achieve the tasks you are given.  If you work as part of an R&D organization, the "Research" part of the job description usually entails installing new packages in order to determine their suitability for the product being developed.  If you need to lose an hour / a day / a week waiting for these packages to be installed, there is a bottom line to the company that these policies are causing.  But, you have to be able to show it.  Otherwise it just falls into a he-said/she-said finger-pointing exercise.